# UItableView search korean text

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, search

In our UItableView search, we are using the below code to search a typed text in the cell content

```
NSComparisonResult result = [eachCellContent compare:searchText options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
```

This is working fine. But this is not working with korean text.

E.g:
suppose one of the cell text is "소".//we are getting this combination by typing these two letters   ㅅ and ㅗ
If we type ㅅ only , our compare method is not working and so not listing the "소". (it is working if we type both ㅅ and ㅗ)

But the above example is working well with AddressBook application.

Is there any other compare method to support this ? (we also need this NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch )

Thanks to reading.

Comment: Yes. Its worked when adding the argument "locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]". Thanks Martin :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to normalize the strings using

```
NSString *normalizedContent = [eachCellContent decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping];
NSString *normalizedSearch = [searchText decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping];
```

and then compare these.

---

**UPDATE:** The following algorithm worked in my test project:

```
NSString *eachCellContent = @"소";
NSString *searchText = @"ㅅ";

NSString *normalizedContent = [eachCellContent decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping];
NSString *normalizedSearch = [searchText decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping];

NSComparisonResult result = [normalizedContent compare:normalizedSearch
                                               options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [normalizedSearch length])
                                                locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
    NSLog(@"same");
}
// Output: same
```

In addition to decomposing the Unicode characters, the "trick" was to use a localized comparison.

Comment: Thanks to the reply. But its not working !
NSString *normalizedContent = [eachCellContent decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping];
NSString *normalizedSearch = [searchText decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping];       
NSComparisonResult result = [normalizedContent compare:normalizedSearch options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [normalizedSearch length])];
if (result == NSOrderedSame){
//not coming here
}

Comment: @david: OK, it was just an idea, but I don't speak Korean, so I could not really test this. - Perhaps you can show the output of `NSLog(@"%@", [eachCellContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding]);` and `NSLog(@"%@", [searchText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding]);` this might help to find the problem.

Comment: @david: I have updated my answer with new code, could you check that?

Comment: Yes, Thanks Martin :). Do you know can we achieve the same when querying from sqlite table (because we are searching from database if too much records -tableview doesn't load all records in this case-)

Comment: @david: Do you use Core Data or plain sqlite?

Comment: @david: Then I can probably not help. (And strictly speaking, this would be a different question, so maybe you can "accept" this answer and post a new question if necessary, perhaps with an additional [sqlite] tag.) - I *assume* that you should 1) store the decomposed strings in the database, 2) decompose the search string, and 3) perform some query that corresponds to `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`.

Comment: np. just asked. Thanks Martin

Comment: oh..sorry, I thought click on up arrow is enough to set it as answer. Now clicked the tick mark.